# extract all attributes from plotly javascript

Tags: javascript, plotly

How to extract all the attributes being used in a plotly JavaScript plot?

For example, I draw a scatter plot at [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZxgXa). How to extract the full [attribute information](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/) of `data` and `layout` being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `newPlot` will return a `Promise` that resolves to the new plot when it is complete. You can get the values of the attributes you want once this promise has resolved.

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout).then(plot => {
    console.log(plot.data);
    console.log(plot.layout);
    console.log(plot._fullLayout);
});
```

Comment: thanks. But it seems that the layout returned is not a full layout reference. It only returns the `yaxis` and `xaxis`.

Comment: Oh, I found it. plot._fullLayout.