# extract attributes from plotly plot (generated in python) javascript

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I am using the python API to generate a plot:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(
        )
fig_html = fig.to_html(
            include_plotlyjs=False,
            full_html=False,
            ...
)
```

I then add the html figure to my webpage, which loads the Plotly CDN in the head section.

I understand that when javascript creates the object through `Plotly.newPlot` you get a reference to the plot object in javascript (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192259/extract-all-attributes-from-plotly-javascript)). But in the case where javascript only has a reference to the raw html div generated through python but not the plotly object, how does one extract plot attributes in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The div DOM object automatically has the `_fullLayout` property, without needing to use any Plotly functions:

```js
document.getElementById("<figure_div_id>")._fullLayout
```